# Trying double entry system for accounting, but getting transaction list is a problem

Tags: sql, sql-server

It's been asked a few times, but more about design. I'm trying to make a little home finance application to learn some new technologies. I've gone with a single double row double entry system design.

[image]

So, a Journal is the root transaction, which has 2 or more Transactions. An Account can be either a Third Party (I paid my mate some cash, I got paid by my company, I paid a restaurant for dinner) or a bank account (I paid money from my credit card)

So, I can Transfer between two accounts.
(I transferred $200 from my Current Account, to my Credit Card account)
I can recieve money.
(I got paid by My Company, into my Current Account.
I can pay someone.
(I paid the restaurant $20 for dinner)

So, lets use the last example. I use my Current Account to pay KFC.
I have two accounts to deal with. KFC, an my current account.

I create a Journal for this transaction.
And then for that Journal, I create two transactions.

First one, is an amount of -20, and the Account is my bank account.
Second one is an amount of +20, and the account is KFC.

I can quickly get the balance of my bank account.

SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Journal WHERE AccountID = MyBankAccountId

Perfect.

But I have an issue.

How do I show a transaction list for my bank account?

[image]

So I want to get a 'Statement' for AccountId 1

[image]

But from this, I can't really tell to whom I paid, or was paid. It only shows the lines related to Account 1.

The data above shows the transactions against the account I care about, but .. I need to show the OTHER account details too. So I need to somehow get 'SourceAccountId' and 'DestinationAccountId'.

Is my design wrong, and I need to go to one line transactions, with a Source and Destination account id in the same row?

The issue I have with that is - I want to be able to assign budgets to my transactions. For example, I was going to add a BudgetId to the Transaction table, allowing me apportion the amounts to different budgets or categories.

(I went to the hardware store, and spend $25. Of that $25, $10 was for my "garden" budget, and $15 was for "internal home decoration" budget.

So my transaction line might have 3 rows.

1 for the credit to the hardware store account for $25.
1 for a debit to my bank account for $10, with a budget Id of my 'Garden Budget'.
1 for a debit to my bank account for $15 with a budget Id of my 'Internal home decoration' budget.

This may be an issue too, as I will then get two 'lines' on my statement for my bank account... One for $15 and one for $10. Maybe I can go one line transaction, but then ... an extra table for the budget apportioning?

That would make getting a balance for an account more tricky. I’d need to check SoutceAccountId and DestinationAccountId.

Any ideas would be great.

Comment: In your first example screenshot it looks like `Id=7` correlates the two transactions. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Two transactions in that case, make up the journal entry. So the debit of one account and the credit to another.

Comment: Typically you do not have "transactions" separately from the journal. The process of applying a transaction involves creating the appropriate number of journal entries, which state the amounts and accounts involved. These are then copied to a ledger table which stores entries by account and then date. The journal is what links ledger entries.

Comment: So it looks like I’m missing a table then? Where would common data be stored. I.e Transaction Date. I’d expect that to exist only once in a table. And then the amount would appear in multiple tables - maybe summed up in one?

Comment: No. You have a journal table. And the journal id links the two transaction records.

Comment: @Craig, I would forget about the notion of "storing a date only in one place". In accounting systems that work, scale, and comply with accounting principles, there is often duplication of data. One of the reasons for storing the date in the journal *and* the ledger, is that journalled transactions may not be applied immediately (for example, they may require further authorisation). Another is that the journal *must* contain all the elements that go into the ledger, but you also want the ledger to be indexable on account and date, without performing joins... (1/2)

Comment: ...the amount of additional space used is insignificant compared to the simplification of normal accounting queries, and the problem of maintaining consistency is (largely) irrelevant because you're not supposed to delete entries once they are applied (you apply reversing or compensating transactions), and you certainly don't update the two tables separately. A third table missing from your schema is that of a "periodic summary balance" - without it, you cannot store a running balance, or archive old detailed data without affecting the running balance of the account. (2/2)

Comment: ... (number 3 of 2 comments!...) The basic principle is that the journal contains all necessary data about a transaction. In a relational database, there will typically be a journal header table and a journal lines table. The ledger is just a projection of journal lines, indexed differently and with a running balance. The summary balance table is just a projection of the ledger, which summarises the ledger balance periodically. Each of these perform necessary and irreducible functions in improving efficiency and allowing the system to clear old data.

Comment: ...(number 4 of 2 comments!...) To give an example of this, producing a typical bank statement would rely on querying the summary balance at the time of the last statement (which is the opening balance of the statement), fetching the ledger entries since, and then entering a new summary balance (which is also forms the closing balance of the statement) which is the opening balance plus the effect of transactions since.

Answer (score 2):

I've worked and built some A/R systems before, it's... interesting to say the least. Typically the way it's done is to record the amount as a positive number (regardless of payment transaction... $100 moved somewhere at the transaction level, the direction is irrelevant), so as it is other than recording +/- in it, I think your transaction table is fine. Might want to add a memo field though so you can record what it was for (ie, let's say you pay the electric bill, you can record that this transaction was for "June '19 bill").

The journal table is where the magic happens.

There's two models I've seen, both work:

```
ID - PKey - Integer - IDENTITY
TransactionID - FKey - Integer - Indicates the parent Transaction
Amount - Decimal - The amount of the journal entry
AccountID - FKey - integer - Indicates the Account the journal entry is for
NetEffect - Bit - Flag which indicates if the item is a Credit (True) or Debit (False)
```

OR...

```
ID - PKey - Integer - IDENTITY
TransactionID - FKey - Integer - Indicates the parent Transaction
DebitAmount - Decimal - Amount of Debit
CreditAmount - Decimal - Amount of Credit
DebitAccountID - FKey - Integer - Indicates the Debit account for the item
CreditAccountID - FKey - Integer - Indicates the Credit account for the item
```

Both would then use the Sum(Debits) - Sum(Debits) to get the balance.

The first one should be explanitory. The second one is closer to a double-entry form. You would use either the Credit OR the Debit fields for an entry, but not both. But it also makes your budget calculations easier.

The Transaction would record $25. The Transactions then record like this:

```
1 -- 1 -- 00 -- 25 -- null -- {account number for garden store}
2 -- 1 -- 10 -- 00 -- {Account for Garden Budget} -- null
3 -- 1 -- 15 -- 00 -- {Internal home Budget} -- null
```

To allocate something to the budget:

```
4 -- 2 -- 25 -- 00 -- null -- {Account for Garden Budget}
5 -- 2 -- 25 -- 00 -- null -- {Internal hom Budget}
6 -- 2 -- 00 -- 50 -- {Your checking account} -- null
```

That moves $50 into your two budgets, 25 for one, 25 for the other, and deducts if from your account.

Then you get paid:

```
7 -- 3 -- 1000 -- 00 -- null -- {Checking account number}
8 -- 3 -- 00 -- 1000 -- {Account for employer} -- null
```

Hopefully that all made sense.

Comment: Yeah. I think it does. It’s pretty. Lose to my initial design. The problem that has stumped me though, is how to get a list of transactions for a particular account. So. I want to see the statement for my checking account. I want it to show as Date, Description, Other Account Name, amount. So using the above examples, I need to see two lines. The payment to the store of $25, and the deposit for my pay for $1000. I’m battling to find an efficient way to get this data.

Comment: That's where the Debit/Credit Account IDs come in ... they would relate back to the appropriate accounts. 

something like this:
```
select *
from Account A
inner join Transaction T on A.Id = T.AccountID
inner join Journal J on T.ID = J.TransactionID
left join Account DAccount on J.DebitAccountID = DAccount.ID
left join Account CAccount on J.CreditAccountID = CAccount.ID
```
You can then flatten it by a group by and summing up the Debit and Credit amounts to get the totals - or use the amount from the Tranaction... and then your Account Names from DAccount and CAccount respecively.

Comment: This looks really promising, @TechGnome - Just trying to work out how I'd get around some requirenments I have. Mainly on the 'Show transactions for an account'. Something like `select ... from Journal inner join Transaction... where DebitAccountId = x OR CreditAccountId = x ...;

Comment: My budgets work differently. They're not really accounts. They're just running totals for a period. So in the example you give, I'd really only have two accounts. My bank account... and the store. So, $25 moves from my account (A debit against my account id) and goes to the store account (a credit against the store accountid). Somehow, I then want to also store that of that $25, 15 was for BudgetA and 10 was for Budget B.

Comment: the last system I worked on had one more level that had a Line Item off the Journal where you could then track that... or off of the parent Transaction, doesn't really matter where I suppose since it's just informational for you. Depending on how nutz you really want to go with it, in a tru GL system it would look like this: Transaction (this is where you'd record $25 spent for ) -> Line item (this is where you show the 10/15 split from the different budgets) -> Journal (this is where the accounts themselves are recorded) ... but for your needs, that's probably overkill.

Comment: in the transaction -> Line Item -> Journal set up you'd end up with 1 Transaction, 2 Line Items, and 4 Journal entries (2 credits and 2 debits for each Line Item) ... like I said, probably overkill for your needs.

Comment: Thanks @TechGnome. So basically on TransactionLine for the whole transaction, with aDate, Description, ..., DrAccount, CrAccount and value... and then off that, a table to record the budget data split. With a TransactionId, and then the budget Id.. and an amount. Does that match what you're suggesting?

Comment: To get a list of transactions for Account A, I'd search TransactionLine where DrAccountId == Account A OR CrAccountId == Account A?